# Cannot create Iron Golems since Minecraft update 1.8.8?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am playing Minecraft on the xbox 360. Following the directions, [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Iron_Golem)
which have worked in the past (prior to the 1.8.8 update), I can no longer create Iron Golems.

I have tried both Pumpkin and Jack-o-lanterns as heads. Is anyone else having this issue?

Has something changed and not made it into the wiki yet? Is there something else I should try?